# Query records through urlsafe key from ndb python

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Hi i inserted a record in ndb. I successfully got its url safe key. Now on the basis of this key i want to query the ndb to fetch the records. How can i do this. Please help.

Code to get URL safe Key.

```
                user = Users()
                user.name = name
                user.email = email
                user.password = hashedPass
                user.ekey = conkey
                user.status = 0


                ke = user.put()

                chk = ke.urlsafe() // got Key Successfully
```

Now on the basis of this key i want to query the db. How can i do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reconstruct the key based on it's [urlsafe](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/keyclass#Constructors) constructor parameter and then call `Key.get` to fetch the entity:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

key = ndb.Key(urlsafe=chk)  # chk is the same string returned from ke.urlsafe() in your example code
entity = key.get()
```